# can the catalytic converter be removed from a 2007 Nissan Maximum XL without creating other problems to the car?

Tags: nissan

Would removing the catalytic converter from a Maximum XL 2007 cause any other problems to the car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Without any other intervention, it will not pass emissions, and a dashlight will be on permanently. Not quite sure what you mean by "other problems"?

Comment: Thanks. Other problems like causing the sensors to malfunction or stop working.

Comment: There are O2 sensors which are located in cat will not longer be sniffing anything. This is what will be causing the dashlight I was talking about above. Other than that, it won't kill your car or anything.

Comment: Depending on where you are removing the cat could be illegal. Won't cause a problem for the car but could for you.

Comment: Do you mean problems other than increasing pollutants coming out of the exhaust?  In the USA and many other places removing the catalytic converter is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

NO.  Removing the cat will cause the fuel injection system to go bananas. **This will greatly degrade engine performance and probably hurt MPG also.**

A lot of people's brains are stuck in the 1970s.  Back then, cars were still carbureted, and smog systems were "bolted on" as an afterthought. Unbolting them could improve performance, yes.  And a lot of people still think that's true.

However by the 1990s, they used better technologies to simply make the engines inherently cleaner.  This technology also made the engines ever more powerful and longer-lasting. I remember the happy day in the 90s when production Chevy small-block V-8s busted 300 *net* horsepower (at the wheels) for the very first time.  For all the fuss about smog, engines were cleaner, more powerful *and long-lasting* than ever.

The smog controls are now fully integrated into the engine, improving performance rather than hurting it.

Breaking smog controls just breaks the engine now.

If you want to improve performance, shut off the A/C when accelerating, and maybe convert to electric power steering so the P/S pump goes away.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the catalytic converter, basically your car will just be louder and you will go through gas quicker. It won't cause any actual car issues though, so you're in the clear.

Comment: If the OP lives in a state or country that requires smog checks to renew vehicle registration or license, or to sell the vehicle, it won't be too long before there is indeed an "actual car issue."